# Mongoose and async.parallel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-async

I want to get an object like the following so I can pass them to my Dust.js template.

```
{ officers:
   [ { _id: '543dcbcf846c139cc042c813', name: 'Alpha' },
     { _id: '543dcc25846c139cc042c814', name: 'Beta' },
     { _id: '543dcd91846c139cc042c815', name: 'Gamma' } ],
  branches:
   [ { _id: '543dcbcf846c139cc042c813', name: 'Alpha' },
     { _id: '543dcc25846c139cc042c814', name: 'Beta' },
     { _id: '543dcd91846c139cc042c815', name: 'Gamma' } ] }
```

Here is my code in controller to get documents using Mongoose and combine them. I always get error 500, is there anything wrong with my code?

```
var Officers = require('../../models/officers');
var Branches = require('../../models/branches');

router.get('/create', function (req, res) {


  async.parallel({
    officers: function(cb){
      Officers.find({}, '_id name', cb);
    },
    branches: function(cb){
      Branches.find({}, '_id name', cb);
    }
  }, function(err, results){
    res.render('companies/create', results);
  });


});
```

Comment: You should handle the error in your callback somehow, otherwise you will have trouble when mongo throws an error and your page renders empty without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with my code above. Turns out I forgot to put this `var async = require('async');` before the code.

```
var Officers = require('../../models/officers');
var Branches = require('../../models/branches');
var async = require('async');

router.get('/create', function (req, res) {
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, just managed to get my head around async parallel queries, incredibly powerful.

Comment: You can also do populate with => Branches.find({}, '_id name').populate('officers').exec(cb);